# VBA module functions not defined access 2010

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to use some functions I created in another .mdb in the project i'm currently working on.
I first went in VBA editor (alt+f11) and right clicked -> export... -> save as module1.bas on my desktop
then I opened my other project and right clicked -> import -> module1.bas
I now see the module1 within my other modules so I use some functions in my code, I clicked save and compile.

```
Compile Error Sub or Function  not defined.
```

It points functions defined in the module I just exported. If I write :

```
module1.functionName parameter
```

It compiles but I usually don't have to type the reference like that. Why is this happening?
How to reference my module to my project?

Comment: edit : nevermind it's still not working

Comment: edit: edit:
Found my mistake by myself. Shamefully Sharing as a reminder to check your code carefully. Subs and Functions were Private in my module.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Please consider posting your findings as an answer to show that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Subs and Function were defined as Private in my module.
Fixed by putting Public instead.

ie:

```
Public Sub subName ()
```